# Weekly Scheduled Exports

Tags: data-export

I have exports set up weekly using the weekly export service. I have it set up for Monday in the middle of the night. But it is Thursday and I just received an email saying that my export was ready. Might this be due to the normal export being very delayed or did someone in my system create an export manually? If it is the latter, is there a way to figure out who did that?

Comment: I've had similar experiences, especially with larger orgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and purely because of the delay!  I have experienced this many times, in fact every week.  Having less number of batches run during this scheduled time, might improve a bit.